# Live Linux to VMware vSphere Hypervisor (former ESXi) fails at 1%

Tags: linux, ubuntu, vmware-esxi, vmware-converter

I am evaluating VMware vSphere Hypervisor (formerly known as ESXi). The server version is 5.0.0. My steps:

1. Open VMware vCenter Converter Standalone (tried versions 4.3 and 5.0);
2. Attempt to convert a Linux box;
3. Successfully contacted the source machine;
4. Successfully contacted the server;
5. Successfully set up my task options;
6. Successfully started the task;

And at 1% the task failed.

The error: `Unable to obtain the IP address of the helper virtual machine.` 
I have DHCP on my network, but just in case I reran the task with a static IP setup for the helper. There it dies after 3 hours and still on 1%. The error message was similar. During the conversion process, I am unable to ping the Converter Helper Server for some unknown reason. It is on the same network, same VLAN as the source Linux box and the ESXi server.

My questions are:

- how to fix this error?;
- is there a better/easier/faster method to convert physical Linux box to VMware VM?

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for my English :)
I had same problem trying to start converter in one of the virtual machines under Win 7 x64 (on the same ESXi). But when I started it on my physical machine under Win 8 x64 the task was done successfully. 
P.S.
The helper in task options has DHCP settings in both cases.

Comment: This is really better as a comment.  Perhaps additional detail might make this a complete answer.